# Disabling specific userforms based on corresponding cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a group of cells, `A1:A5`, that each have a corresponding combobox user form, combobox1-5. If any of these cells are empty, I need to disable their combobox. I'm sure I could do it with something like:

```
Dim count As Integer
count = 0
    Do Until count = 4
        If Cells(1 + count, "A").Value = "" Then
            Select Case count
                Case 0
                    combobox1.disable
                Case 1
                    combobox2.disable
                Case 2
                    combobox3.disable
                Case 3
                    combobox4.disable
                Case 4
                    combobox5.disable
            End Select
        End If
        count = count + 1
    Loop
```

..but it seems like there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: FWIW a `UserForm` has very little to do with MSForms **controls** on a worksheet. You're looking for the `Enabled` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop:

```
Dim n As Integer

for n = 1 to 5
    Me.controls("combobox" & n).Enabled = (ActiveSheet.Cells(n, "A").Value <> "")
next
```

Comment: Perfect. That IS much simpler. Thanks!